# how to create a modal pop up with html support ( links must be clickable ) in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how to create a modal pop up with html support ie with a href link  ( links must be clickable ) in unity. I want to create a popup that list stores and the link , when user clicks on the story link , the link must be opened in a browser ( as the story link will contain picture and videos)

I tried this but a href links not working on this modal pop up

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;

    // example:
    // HFTDialog.MessageBox("error", "Sorry but you're S.O.L", () => { Application.Quit() });

    public class HFTDialog : MonoBehaviour {

        Rect m_windowRect;
        Action m_action;
        string m_title;
        string m_msg;

        static public void MessageBox(string title, string msg, Action action)
        {
            GameObject go = new GameObject("HFTDialog");
            HFTDialog dlg = go.AddComponent<HFTDialog>();
            dlg.Init(title, msg, action);
        }


        static public void CloseMessageBox(GameObject go)
        {
           Destroy(go.gameObject);
        }

        void Init(string title, string msg, Action action)
        {
            m_title = title;
            m_msg = msg;
            m_action = action;
        }

        void OnGUI()
        {
            const int maxWidth = 640;
            const int maxHeight = 480;

            int width = Mathf.Min(maxWidth, Screen.width - 20);
            int height = Mathf.Min(maxHeight, Screen.height - 20);
            m_windowRect = new Rect(
                (Screen.width - width) / 2,
                (Screen.height - height) / 2,
                width,
                height);

            m_windowRect = GUI.Window(0, m_windowRect, WindowFunc, m_title);
        }

        void WindowFunc(int windowID)
        {
            const int border = 10;
            const int width = 50;
            const int height = 25;
            const int spacing = 10;

            Rect l = new Rect(
                border,
                border + spacing,
                m_windowRect.width - border * 2,
                m_windowRect.height - border * 2 - height - spacing);
            GUI.Label(l, m_msg);

            Rect b = new Rect(
                m_windowRect.width - width - border,
                m_windowRect.height - height - border,
                width,
                height);

            if (GUI.Button(b, "close"))
            {
                Destroy(this.gameObject);
                m_action();
            }

        }
    }
```

I want something similar to this but ahref links must be supported in the popup

[image: Pop up window]

Comment: And why can't you have your images and videos within unity ? There is no such things as "html link" in unity, it's not web based. There is c# function that can open application such as the browser, but why would you do it for this use case ?

Comment: @Jichael I want to list all stories and corresponding story links, when one story link is clicked user must read the full story in a browser window

Comment: Are you sure that's [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) (a Javascript derivative created for Unity) and not C#?

Comment: The Unity asset store contains some [Web Browser assets like this one](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/3d-webview-for-windows-and-macos-154144) which you may wanna look into.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:unity-container]

Comment: Just use a button with a transparent background that calls `Application.OpenURL()`